# How do I get my browser read external css?

Tags: html, css

[[image: here is the html page with dev tools pulled upcss page (gotten to by clicking style.css in dev tools from previous)]I've tried seemingly everything and nothing is working for this seemingly simple and mundane css and html. I'm using external css as I was told that's easier on a larger scale for later projects but right now I'm just learning basics. Before you ask, yes, they are both in the same folder and using developer tools I can see that it is properly linking, but it appears the browser isn't reading it and it just looks like a text doc. Running the code works perfectly through here so I don't understand what's wrong. I'm using safari on MacBook and have also tried chrome - should I use a different browser or?
Edit: As you can see in the images my user profile includes Null (part of my name) I believe that's what's messing with it, is there a way around that?

```css
h1{
    color: red;
}
p{
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Coding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>First code</h1>
        <p>Welcome to my first set of code!</p>
    </header> 

    <NAV>
        <ul>
            <li><a href "#">nice</a></li>
            <li><a href "#">cool</a></li>
            <li><a href "#">rad</a></li>
        </ul>
    </NAV> 
    <footer>
        <p>Nice amiright?</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put a screen capture of how the folders and files look in your computer, and also the code that is supposed to load the css

Comment: add type="text/css" to link ?,  also try use path relative to root (if you have a local server) href="/style.css"

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` like this

Comment: Reference :https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: The type attribute it optional. It won’t solve the problem.

Comment: “ using developer tools I can see that it is properly linking” - what exactly does it show. A screenshot might be useful.

Comment: So I believe I found the problem; my last name is, "Null" so when linking to the css file it uses my name in the link which I believe nullifies the code. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @k0sh3r — That isn't the problem.

Comment: The code in the screenshot **doesn't match the code in the question**. It has `type="css"` in it. Remove that.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show that the stylesheet is properly linking, you need to show the Network tab for that.

Comment: Problem's been solved, apparently although I moved both files into the same folder they weren't set to save there so while I had the files in a folder together, every time I'd press save it would just save to another location. Thanks for all the help everybody :)

Comment: @k0sh3r — You should delete the question then. That type of silly mistake hasn't got any useful long term value here and it is just attracting wrong answers.

Answer (score -1):

We have two various types of Href

1. Absolute Path [it's added through an External Link]
2. Relative Path [it's added through an Internal Link]

The way you wanted to have is definitely ***the first item of*** the above-mentioned issues.
It'd be like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/[Path]/file.css">
```

Comment: It seems to me that your answer is not the answer to the question posed, answers were given in the comments. from the question we see: the browser isn't reading it and it just looks like a text doc, the problem is the missing type tag, and not a problem on the link

Answer (score -1):

There actually 2 ways to achieve that. The first Method has been already stated and that is to link the external CSS inside the head-element of your website:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="url to the external .css" />
```

The second method however has not been mentioned yet which imo is the better one. Create an own .css file and link your website to it. Then add following line at the very top of your css file. That allows you do overwrite or change specific element of the css that you might cant access on your own:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap');
```

Comment: They are already using the first approach. The second approach is useless if they can’t get the first to work. Please read the comments on the question: they were saving the file in the wrong directory.

Comment: as you see in my anwser I have seen th commentts. however I'm a huge fan of giving a complete anwser instead of a partial.

Comment: Answers are supposed to *solve the problem*, this doesn't do that.

Comment: of course doe the anwser solve the issue. the missing type class has been included for the head element.

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional. There is no case where adding it to a `<link>` element will cause a stylesheet written in CSS to load where it wasn't before. You said you had read the comments, if you had you would have noticed that the solution was to *save the CSS file in the correct place*.